# Python: appending a list to over 255 elements

Tags: python, list, append

I have a list which i append every time i run a for-loop.
This loop runs for more than 255 times but i cannot append the list beyond 255 elements.
How can i fix this problem?

```
for x in y:  
        a = json.dumps(b)
        c.append(a)
```

Comment: Are you saying you want to stop at 255 or would you like a "moving window" of 255 elements?

Comment: I clearly misunderstood the question ... I think keats understood correctly

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this

Slicing:

```
c = [json.dumps(b) for x in y[0:255]]
```

Or using enumerate:

```
for ind, x in enumerate(y):
    if ind == 255:
         break
    c.append(json.dumps(b))
```

Or you could use a while loop, it's easy because `len` is `O(1)` for a `list`:

```
while len(c) < 255:
    c.append(json.dumps(b))
```